How to Count Countries from Multiple Lists that Match a Given Region?
I want to count how many countries from several comma-separated lists match a given region
I'm working on a project where I have several comma-separated lists of countries, and I need to count how many countries from these lists belong to a specific region.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x4jdnOjDndEYzEYWRd-_l8Wguza9cjq9Im4dBr2ejsU/edit?usp=sharing
note: I am using excel

Please edit your question to show what you have tried, and your expected results from your data.

Give a try to the following formula-
=LET(
a,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,B2:B6),,", "),
b,FILTER(Countries!B2:B9,Countries!C2:C9=Sales!F2),
SUM(MAP(a,LAMBDA(x,--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(x,b))))))



SUM(--MAP( converts TRUE to 1. Result is based on your sample data.
SUM(BYROW(csv_countries, count_region)) to get total for all.
=LAMBDA(
    csv_countries,
    region_to_count,
    countries,
    region_for_country,
    LET(
        count_region, LAMBDA(csv,
            LET(
                split, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(csv, ",")),
                result, SUM(
                    --(
                        MAP(
                            split,
                            LAMBDA(c,
                                XLOOKUP(
                                    c,
                                    countries,
                                    region_for_country,
                                    ""
                                ) = region_to_count
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                result
            )
        ),
        BYROW(csv_countries, count_region)
    )
)(B2:B6, F2, Countries!B2:B100, Countries!C2:C100)


